# PCB track clearance

Tags: pcb, altium

in the PCB I am designing there is 0.88mm between one track and a through hole pad. Between the track and the pad there is a DC voltage difference of around 425V.

Clearance calculators like [this one](http://www.smpspowersupply.com/ipc2221pcbclearance.html) specify a minimum clearance of 0.8mm for 500V if "external conductors coated" are used. If that is the case, I am safe, but I am not sure about what "external conductors coated" refers to.

The track and the pad are in the top layer, so I assume they are external, but are they coated? that coating is referred to a standard solder mask or is it a special one?

EDIT:

If the clearance is not enough I have two options:
1. Apply a coating after soldering. (I am not sure how yet)
2. Cut the problematic track and use a wire instead

What do you think it is best?
this is the problematic track:

[image]

Comment: IPC-2221A (6.3 - Electrical Clearance): Typical applications (like yours) are in the category B4 "External Conductors, with Permanent Polymer Coating (Any Elevation)". This is a pcb with solder resist. Clearance rule is 301-500V : 0.8mm. I think you can leave it as it is without conformal coating.

Comment: Now that you explained that the solder mask is the "Polymer coating" it looks better.. :) Thanks!

Comment: In this particular case, you can solve this by routing the track around.

Comment: Yes, that would be the safest solution, sadly the PCB is already if the manufacturing process and it can not be changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard solder mask is not a conformal coating.

IPC-SM-840C:

> Solder mask materials covered in the standard are not intended for use as a substitute for conformal coatings that are applied after assembly to cover components, component leads/terminations and solder connections.

Related to IPC-2221A (4.5.2.1) there are some types and requirements for the thickness:

- Type AR - Acrylic Resin : 0.03 - 0.13 mm
- Type ER - Epoxy Resin : 0.03 - 0.13 mm
- Type UR - Urethane Resin : 0.03 - 0.13 mm
- Type SR - Silicone Resin : 0.05. - 0.21 mm
- Type XY Paraxylylene Resin : 0.01 - 0.05 mm

IPC-2221A (6.3.4):

> Typical applications are computers, office equipment, and
>   communication equipment, bare boards operating in controlled
>   environments in which the bare boards have a permanent
>   polymer coating on both sides.
>
> After they are assembled and soldered the boards are not conformal
>   coated, leaving the solder joint and soldered land uncoated.
>
> Note: All conductors, except for soldering lands, must be
>   completely coated in order to ensure the electrical clearance
>   requirements in this category for coated conductors.

"permanent polymer coating" stands for solder mask / solder resist.

So when you don't do a conformal coating *after* the component assembly, you only can relate on the ***uncoated***  or  ***with Permanent Polymer Coating*** categories for your clearances.